# split pandas data frame into multiple of 4 rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of 100 rows, I want to split them into multiple of 4 and then perform operations on it, i.e., first perform operation on first four rows, then on the next four rows and so on.

Note: Rows are independent of each other.

I don't know how to do it. Can somebody pls help me, I would be extremely thankful to him/her.

Answer (score 0):

i will divide `df` per 2 row (simple example)
and make list `dfs`

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list('ABCDE'), columns=['value'])
```

`df`

```
    value
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   D
4   E
```

**Code**

grouper for grouping

```
grouper = pd.Series(range(0, len(df))) // 2
```

`grouper`

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    2
dtype: int64
```

divide to list

```
g = df.groupby(grouper)
dfs = [g.get_group(x) for x in g.groups]
```

result(`dfs`):

```
[  value
 0     A
 1     B,
   value
 2     C
 3     D,
   value
 4     E]
```

**Check**

```
dfs[0]
```

output:

```
value
0   A
1   B
```

Comment: Quite brief and helpful, Thank you for your time.

Comment: What would be the logic if I want to print 'C'?